# Flutter - Selected items move to top of ListView

Tags: android, ios, listview, dart, flutter

I’ve been looking for a way to **permanently** move selected items to the top of a ListView in flutter.

This would work by pressing an `iconbutton`, next to a `ListView` element, and having this element move to the top upon a `refresh`.

If possible, I’d like the icon button to become `enabled` (ie glow / light up) when it’s enabled, and `disabled` (greyed out, but still press-able) when disabled.

I wouldn’t be able to fit in all my code in this question, so all that along with `_getListItemUi` are available at: https://github.com/Jak3-02/myproject2

**This is what my current ListView looks like:**

```
Widget _cryptoWidget() {
    return new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _currencies.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final int i = index ~/ 2;
                  final Crypto currency = _currencies[i];
                  final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % _colors.length];
                  if (index.isOdd) {
                    return new Divider();
                  }
                  return _getListItemUi(currency, color);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      );
  }
```

Thank you, all ideas are appreciated. :)

Comment: You could have a list of selected items that are used as the first children of the `ListView`.

Comment: Could you please show me how I would code this into my project? Also how I would be able to allow the user to select an item to add to the list of selected items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a class project, so I'm going to point you in the right direction to figure this out for yourself.

Notice the Item Builder in your code. It reads the _currencies list and builds the corresponding widgets. *What would happen if you [rearranged the items](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html) in _currencies and ran this code again?*

How would you get the _cryptoWidget to redraw when its _currencies list changes? *Would you use a Stateful widget or a Stateless one? Which of these redraws itself when its data changes?*

You want a clickable icon that can look different when it's enabled and disabled. *Have you looked in the [Widget Catalog](https://flutter.io/widgets/)?*

With these notes, you should be able to solve this pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put this together, it’s helped me a huge amount. :)